# Find item in array returned from sql query

Tags: python, list, find

I have an array(list?), like below, which is the result of a sql query.

```
lstLineRouteKey = [('1203/1000/2', 1, 'DVN 1000'), ('1212/1000/2', 2, 'RKS 1000'), ('1189/1000/2', 3, 'USH 1000'), ('1201/1000/2', 4, 'ANA 1000'), ('1232/1000/2', 5, 'CLB 1000'), ('1207/1000/2', 6, 'HRY 1000'), ('1162/1000/2', 7, 'LBR 1000')]
```

What I'm trying to do is find the first(only) instance of '1212/1000/2' and retrieve the value to the right of it, 2 .

I have managed to do that with a for loop, below, but it is very inefficient, as it's looping through the entire list, even after it's found a match.

```
for id,row in enumerate(lstLineRouteKey):
                    lst = list(row)
                    for id,s in enumerate(lst):
                        if lst[0] == '1212/1000/2':
                            ID = str(lst[1]);
```

I've been unsuccessful with the methods(.find, .map) I've found thus far, as none of the lists resemble my structure above.  Assistance will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you're looking for the *first* record matching some condition? You can do that with `next`.

```
>>> next(x[1] for x in lstLineRouteKey if x[0] == '1212/1000/2')
2
```

The advantage of `next` is that it is very *efficient*. It will exhaust the generator expression, returning the first value that satisfies that expression. `next` will not iterate over the whole list if it does not need to.

To visualise what happens, consider a list comprehension of the form `y = [x[1] for x in lstLineRouteKey if x[0] == '1212/1000/2']` generating a list of K elements. In this case, `next` would return the value of `y[0]`. In actuality, *the intermediate list is **not** generated!* This is why it is efficient.

---

If there's a possibility that the record doesn't exist, `next` may raise a `StopIteration`. In which case, pass a default argument to `next`. Here's an example

```
>>> print(next((x[1] for x in lstLineRouteKey if x[0] == '1212/1000/3'), None))
None
```

Comment: string var = str(cabinet);      So hard-coding the string '1212/1000/2' works, but I cannot pass a string var in place of it.  I continue to get a  name 'string var' is not defined.

Comment: @vvPULSEvv can you open a new question? I need more information.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is [**`break`**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#break) statement:

> It terminates the nearest enclosing loop, skipping the optional else clause if the loop has one.

You may use it in your code like:

```
lstLineRouteKey = [('1203/1000/2', 1, 'DVN 1000'), ('1212/1000/2', 2, 'RKS 1000'), ('1189/1000/2', 3, 'USH 1000'), ('1201/1000/2', 4, 'ANA 1000'), ('1232/1000/2', 5, 'CLB 1000'), ('1207/1000/2', 6, 'HRY 1000'), ('1162/1000/2', 7, 'LBR 1000')]

my_result = None

for line_route in lstLineRouteKey:
    if line_route[0] == '1212/1000/2':
        my_result = line_route[1]
        break   # on reaching here, your for loop will be terminated 
                # (no further execution)
```

Comment: @srig Thanks! Yes, that's exactly what I meant :D

Comment: It caught my eyes because I came up with the same answer. Never mind :)

Comment: Thank you Moinuddin Quadri !

Answer (score 0):

Once you find the item at index `[0]` in a `tuple` matches your query, you could assign the value at index `[1]` to `ID` and break out of the loop.

```
lstLineRouteKey = [('1203/1000/2', 1, 'DVN 1000'), ('1212/1000/2', 2, 'RKS 1000'), ('1189/1000/2', 3, 'USH 1000'), ('1201/1000/2', 4, 'ANA 1000'), ('1232/1000/2', 5, 'CLB 1000'), ('1207/1000/2', 6, 'HRY 1000'), ('1162/1000/2', 7, 'LBR 1000')]

ID = ''

for x, y, z in lstLineRouteKey:
    if x == '1212/1000/2':
        ID = str(y)
        break
```